# Find mean / median point based on ID attribute and point density (hot spots)

Tags: arcgis-pro, clustering, centroids, hot-spot

I have a point feature class within ArcGIS Pro, with 10.000 features, data are structured like this:

```
ObjectID |  MemberID | Lat | Long
1             ID_1     Y1    X1
2             ID_1     Y2    X2
3             ID_1     Y3    X3
4             ID_2     Y4    X4
5             ID_2     Y5    X5
...
10.000        ID_n     Yn    Xn
```

Based on:

- `MemberID`
- Density of points (sometime I have points very far each other and I want to give a low weight to the outliers)

I would like to have as output:

- A point feature class, in which each point represents the mean/median/avg/bestRepresentation of location for each `MemberID`.

I already tried with the centroid, but I don't like the result as I would also like to take into consideration the density of points (and give a low weight to the outliers)

Is there a specific tool to do this or should I built a custom one?
Once I receive suggestions I could start to write some code below.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro, sorry.

Comment: Whats your definition of mean, median, best etc.?

Comment: I think the *Directional Distribution* tool would be your best bet. [Esri docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/directional-distribution.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Explore the [Geographic Distribution Toolset](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/an-overview-of-the-measuring-geographic-distributions-toolset.htm) in the Spatial Statistics Toolbox. There are tools that locate a central feature for a set of points. You would typically set the case field for grouping, so in your case your `memberID`.